# Sending data with a PHP form

Tags: html, php

I'm using this **[form](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete)** from w3schools but this example shows the sent info on the same page. What should I do to send my info to my email? Also, I'll like to have some kind of either a thanks you page or a message on the same page saying the message was sent. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: @Stanyer What should I do to send.....? It doesn't sound like I'm asking for you to write anything. Also, adding a echo for the Thank you page is more helpful. You need to relax my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the wonderful [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class and at the examples in the "examples" folder.

Then you set your settings like in the examples and everything is fine.

It's very easy to handle.

What you need:

- PHPMailer Class
- SMTP Server (for example gmail)

Then you send the mail and add the line:

```
echo "Thank you";
```

after the send-command.

Comment: I tried echo "Thank you"; and it works but I'm getting a blank page with the 'Thank you' page, is missing all the style.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions on the internet! Instead of using the explanation of w3schools you can use the following tutorial.

It has all your needs. Especially the Server-side processing - which will send an email to you. You only have to fill in your email address.

[Complete Tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html)